# How can I make my users to join a maximum of 2 users "room" in php

Tags: php

When 1 press the button should be placed in a queue to find the next user that pressed the button when there are 2 users that pressed they will join a private room that only they should see.Is this possible?I really need a tutorial or some example codes if you can give me,hope I didn't waste anyone time.
If isn't possible in php can it be done with js or ajax?

Comment: a "room" ? like a chatroom? You have a websocket server running?

Comment: yes like a chatroom but I don't need the chat,and I dont have server im using localhost,I downloaded a chat room and worked fine

Comment: a chat plugin actually thats what I've downloaded and worked on localhost

Comment: all i will suggest is that you perhaps investigate `node.js` - it offers the functionality required to accomplish your objective

Comment: ill read about it,do you think would be bad to make like 1000 .php pages and redirect 2 users in one of this page which are like some kind of rooms?like room 1 2 3 ... 1000 xD